# What is the best way to find out the candidate group a task?

Tags: process, business-process-management, camunda

After I loaded a List of tasks with a taskQuery

```
taskService.createTaskQuery()
            .processDefinitionKey(PROCESSKEY)
            .taskCandidateGroupIn(list).initializeFormKeys().list()
```

What is the best way to find out the candidate group of every [task](http://docs.camunda.org/7.2/api-references/javadoc/org/camunda/bpm/engine/task/Task.html)?
I want to display it in a JSF view, but the class Task has no corresponding field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is to write a custom query that gives you all task information the way you need them with on select. You do not want to start  looping over result lists and sending one or more query per item, especially not in a high performance application as your task list.

Check the [custom query documentation](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/real-life/how-to/#process-engine-custom-queries) for details.

Answer (score 6):

You can get a task's identity links using the task service. Among other relations, the candidate group relation is expressed as an identity link. The following code filters a task's identity links for those that represent candidate groups:

```java
List<IdentityLink> identityLinks = taskService.getIdentityLinksForTask(task.getId());

for (IdentityLink identityLink : identityLinks) {
  String type = identityLink.getType(); 
  /* type corresponds to the constants defined in IdentityLinkType.
  "candidate" identitifies a candidate relation */

  String groupId = identityLink.getGroupId();

  if (IdentityLinkType.CANDIDATE.equals(type) && groupId != null) {
    // we have found a candidate group; do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only select task which have a candidate groups.

```
List<Task> candidateGroupList = taskService.createTaskQuery().withCandidateGroups().list();
```